# zsh autocompletion, second parameter based on first

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I need to auto-complete two parameters of a function, where the second parameter depends on the first one.

An example: the first parameter of a function "foo" can have values of "a" or "b". The second parameter can have values "10" or "11" in case the first parameter is "a", and "20" and "21" in case the first parameter is "b". So the following combinations of the parameters are legal:

```
foo a 10
foo a 11
foo b 20
foo b 21
```

The combinations are known upfront (they can be hardcoded).

The [zsh completion system doc](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html) is quite obscure and the great [How To](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org) didn't solve my problem neither. The closest would be to use `_arguments`, possibly with state action, but I didn't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

`_arguments` would make sense if you've got options mixed in with the arguments that you've described. Otherwise, just look in the `$words` array for the previous word - something like:

```
if (( CURRENT == 1 )); then
   _wanted letters expl letter compadd a b
else
  case $words[1] in
    a) numbers=( 10 11 ) ;;
    b) numbers=( 20 21 ) ;;
  esac
  _wanted numbers expl number compadd -a numbers
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my case with the following:

```
IFS='
'
local -a options
_arguments "1:first:->first" "*:next:->next"
case "$state" in
    first)
        for o in $(_command_to_autocomplete_first); do
            options+=("$o")
        done
        _describe 'values' options
    ;;
    next)
        for o in $(_command_to_complete_others $words[2]); do
            options+=("$o")
        done
        _describe 'values' options
    ;;
esac
```